# Maven - Reading a property from an external properties file

Tags: maven, build, release-management

I have a property file with the following

```
junit.version=3.8.1
dbcp.version=5.5.27
oracle.jdbc.version=10.2.0.2.0
```

I try to read those properties from my pom file as shown below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
  <version>${oracle.jdbc.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <!-- Associate the read-project-properties goal with the initialize phase, to read the properties file. -->
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>../live.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I find that when i run mvn clean install it does not find the properties, instead it comes up with the following errors:

```
'dependencies.dependency.version' for junit:junit:jar must be a valid version but is '${junit.version}'. @ line 23, column 16
'dependencies.dependency.version' for dbcp:dbcp:jar must be a valid version but is '${dbcp.version}'. @ line 31, column 12
'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar must be a valid version but is '${oracle.jdbc.version}'. @ line 37, column 13
```

The above failures appear to be in situations where i refer to the property when i declare the dependency. I found that in some other situations the property is read from the file. 
For example it works if i use a property on the project version tag (not dependency version)

It seems that the property is not read from the file if it is referred to from the dependency declaration but is read if referred to from anywhere else.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the point of having those versions in a separate file?

Comment: I am sharing that properties file with another project which creates a war overlay using the versions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `initialize` phase is not part of the [clean lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). You need to also bind your properties plugin to `pre-clean` phase.

However, the dependency resolution runs before resolving and executing other plugins, so your approach won't work.

The proper way to deal with that would be to move dependency versions into a parent pom.xml and use the same parent pom in both of your projects.

Comment: Which phase should i use to ensure that the properties are loaded regarded of the mvn command?

Comment: I already answered that. The mvn clean command is using differed lifecycle that has completely different phases from the default lifecycle (e.g. mvn package or mvn install). Please follow the link to documentation from my answer.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? <phase>pre-clean,initialize</phase>

Comment: I tried to add both pre-clean and intialize but it didnt work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question more carefully... You can't specify multiple phases in <phase> element. But you can't use properties loaded by properties-maven-plugin to specify versions of dependencies. I updated my answer with proper solution.

Comment: I am trying to find the maven document where it states "dependency resolution runs before executing other plugins" so that I can get a more indepth insight into it. Do you have the link to such a document?

Comment: JackDev no idea if such document exists (you may want to post a separate question for that). However, I am certain that how it is implemented in Mavens from version 1 to 3.x... If you think about it, that's the only way to guarantee reproducible builds.

Comment: so is there any other way we can achieve same results ? I have got many environments and each needs different version of a jar.

Comment: "If you think about it, that's the only way to guarantee reproducible builds." Yea reproducible with duplicate entries for library versions, which yields a very high probability of conflict when your application has 2 dosen components with intertwined dependency graphs, how f-ing brilliant, the depth of thought is staggering

Answer (score 2):

u can define like this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>pre-clean-config</id>
                    <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>config.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                <id>initialize-config</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>config.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I have exactly same pom and packaging type is POM. Inside pom, I have following dependency
       <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>${testing.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

I am running project with command 'mvn clean package -DskipTests'. But still it is not resolving dependency.