# Maven dependencies - how to add dependencies based on classpath properties

Tags: maven

Is it not possible to include dependencies based on class properties? E.g. if I am building a framework that I want to integrate with any customer system, the type of DB the customer uses could be a variable but my framework may use it if it can acquire a data source. So in this case, my Maven project should be able to integrate with any DB by declaring the corresponding DB war as dependency.

E.g.

```
<dependency>
   <artifactId>${database.artifactId}</artifactId>
   ....
</dependency>
```

But this `database.artifactId` in itself will be read from properties file that may be accesible to customer code, so the idea of having parent pom declare the versions and artifactId as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912632/maven-reading-a-property-from-an-external-properties-file) may not suit my case.

Is there a work around or is this use case itself so wrong? I strongly think if we build a framework that is more like a product the customer can integrate with, this flexibility of declaring any runtime dependency based on propertie should be there.

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: Can't your library just depend on JDBC API, hence it is compatible to whatever DB implementation the client uses?

Comment: You are trying to couple the implementation with your framework which in my opinion is simply a contradiction. A framework shouldn't depend on a particular implementation only on interfaces (API's). It will be solved by later dependency injection frameworks like spring or guice or whatever. So you have to compile and build against an interface (API). If you correctly use only interface dependency the user of your library can simply solve it by adding a correct implementation dependency to its build.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it is done with Maven.

If, as in your case, you write a framework that may use different dependencies, then you do not somehow conditionally depend on the concrete implementation. This would not work, as the exact list of dependencies is constructed at build time (i.e. when the Maven artifact of you framework is built and installed).

Rather, there should be a special Maven artifact which describes just the interface of the functionality that you need. This artifact will typically contain the (Java) interfaces your framework needs; this is what your framework will depend on.

Then, when using your framework, a concrete implementation of these interfaces must be included - by the people using your framework, because only they know which implementation they use.

This is explained for example in "Maven by Example", chapter ["7.10.1. Programming to Interface Projects"](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring-sect-conclusion.html).

---

Example:

- **JDBC**: The interface is part of the JDK, so a framework that uses JDBC does not need to declare any special dependencies (if JDBC were not part of the JDK, you would depend on a Maven artifact like "jdbc-api" or similar). A software that actually uses JDBC will have to depend on whatever JDBC driver it actually uses (Oracle, HSQL etc.).

Comment: I am indeed using a contract-based approach. But, there is some database work specific to my framework needs and I want to do that in whatever database the users have. Although I can use the JDBC or ORM, to establish database connections, I will still need the runtime database JAR as maven dependency, isn't it? Do you suggest that I also expect a DataSource object to be provided by contract implementor (will it look a good idea)? Won't the Datasources for my app have to be maintained separately by app server, as the contact implementation can use its own DataSource?

Comment: @Paddy: *"I will still need the runtime database JAR as maven dependency, isn't it?"* Yes, but this dependency will not be declared by your framework, but by the project using your framework. Only that project will know which database JAR it needs.

Comment: @Paddy: (ctd.) *"Do you suggest that I also expect a DataSource object to be provided by contract implementor"* Yes, that's exactly how it's usually done. See e.g. here how to do it with Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html Obviously, you *cannot* provide the DataSource, as you'd need to know stuff like the DB server name and login.

Comment: although I call it a framework, it will be the app hosted as a WAR and will integrate with client implementation. So my app will still need the dependency - but as you pointed out, if the contract also provides a DataSource, then it solves the problem. But this would bind the contract implementor to provide me a DataSource, which is like an anti-pattern - my contract is a business contract, not a technical one.

Comment: @Paddy: You seem to have an unusual Maven project structure. You should probably expand your question with an explanation of how you want your product to work, then maybe we can help. At any rate, if you are building a framework, then the customer-specific parts must depend on your framework, not the other way round.

Comment: OK, let me try to explain as much as I can. I have a services layer that is going to consume the contract and expose as REST urls. This is my framework or you can call template of a real app that will work only when a contract implementation is plugged, which will be customer-specific and contact their database etc. My framework or template app whatever should be integrable with any customer implementation. At the same time, my services layer has to do minimal DB work like authorization as per user, which is my app-specific logic. That's why I need the DB access. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Paddy: Sorry, the comments don't really work for extended discussion. Please edit that information into your question, so others will see it.

Comment: Sure I will, but your thoughts (@sleske) on the scenario I explained?

Comment: @Paddy: If I feel I can help, I'll edit my answer after you edited the question :-).